# Help with ContentSearch LINQ query syntax

Tags: content-search

Here is my scenario:

- Bucket of sitecore items of a specific template
- This template has a field tags(which is a treelist) where you can associate x items there.
  I'm building a query using lucene to retrieve all the items from the index that have the same tags as my current item. How can I do that?

My code is not 100% done because getting this relashionship is not working properly.

```cs
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName).CreateSearchContext())
{
    //Filters related articles
    var relatedSearchQuery = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
        .Where( item => item.ItemId != currentArticle.Id.ToID()
```

How do I make that relationship as I can't make standard Linq queries at this point?

Comment: Have you added the `Tags` field to the `SearchResultItem` class?

Comment: no. I just created the Tags field on Sitecore and have published and reindexed but that's how far it goes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To be able to search on a field in the Sitecore SearchAPI you need to add that field to a model. So you could create a new class derived from `SearchResultItem` and add your tags field in:

```cs
public class MySearchResultItem: SearchResultItem
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof (IndexFieldEnumerableConverter))]
    [IndexField("tags")]
    public IEnumerable<ID> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

I'm here assuming that your `Tags` field is a list type field that stores the Guids of the tags. The `IndexField` attribute tells Sitecore what the field name is for this property. The `TypeConverter` field tells the API how to convert the value stored in the index to the C# type.

Now you have that you can use it in your Linq query:

```cs
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName).CreateSearchContext())
{
    //Filters related articles
    var relatedSearchQuery = context.GetQueryable<MySearchResultItem>()
        .Where(item => item.ItemId != currentArticle.Id.ToID() &&
                       item.Tags.Contains(currentArticle.TagId))
```

Here I am assuming a single tag on the current article.

If you need to compare a list with a list it gets a bit more complicated. In that case you need to create a search extension that will build that query.

Here is the code. I have included the comments in the code to explain what is going on.

```cs
public static class SearchExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TSource> ContainsOr<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> queryable, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, IEnumerable values) where TKey : IEnumerable
    {
        return Contains(queryable, keySelector, values, true);
    }

    public static IQueryable<TSource> ContainsAnd<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> queryable, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, IEnumerable values) where TKey : IEnumerable
    {
        return Contains(queryable, keySelector, values, false);
    }

    public static IQueryable<TSource> Contains<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> queryable, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector, IEnumerable values, bool orOperator) where TKey : IEnumerable
    {
        const string methodName = "Contains";

        // Ensure the body of the selector is a MemberExpression
        if (!(keySelector.Body is MemberExpression))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression must be a member expression");
        }

        var typeOfTSource = typeof(TSource);
        var typeOfTKey = typeof(TKey);

        // x
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeOfTSource);

        // Create the enumerable of constant expressions based off of the values
        var constants = values.Cast<object>().Select(id => Expression.Constant(id));

        IEnumerable<MethodCallExpression> expressions = Enumerable.Empty<MethodCallExpression>();
        /*
         * Create separate MethodCallExpression objects for each constant expression created
         *
         * Each expression will effectively be like running the following;
         * x => x.MyIdListField.Contains(AnId)
         *
         * Check to see if we can find a method on TKey type which matches the method we want to run.
         * We do this because not all types use the static IEnumerable extension e.g. the String class
         * has it's own implementation of .Contains.
         *
         * If we can't find a matching method then we try to run the extension method found in Enumerable
         */
        if (typeOfTKey.GetMethods().Any(m => m.Name.Equals(methodName)))
        {
            var method = typeOfTKey.GenericTypeArguments.Any() ? typeOfTKey.GetMethod(methodName, typeOfTKey.GenericTypeArguments) : typeOfTKey.GetMethod(methodName);

            /*
             * instance     -> this would be property we want to run the expession on e.g.
             *                 IQueryable<MyPocoTemplate>.Where(x => x.MyIdListField)
             *                 so keySelector.Body will contain the "x.MyIdListField" which is what we want to run
             *                 each constant expression against
             * method       -> the method to run against the instance e.g. "x.MyIdListField.Contains(...)"
             * arguments    ->
             *      constant    ->  this is the constant expression (value) to be passed to the method
             */
            expressions = constants.Select(constant => Expression.Call(keySelector.Body, method, constant));
        }
        else
        {
            /*
             * type             ->  we need to specify the type which contains the method we want to run
             * methodName       ->  in this instance we need to specify the Contains method
             * typeArguments    ->  the type parameter from TKey
             *                      e.g. if we're passing through IEnumerable<Guid> then this will pass through the Guid type
             *                      this is because we're effectively running IEnumerable<Guid>.Contains(Guid guid) for each
             *                      guid in our values object
             * arguments        ->
             *      keySelector.Body    ->  this would be property we want to run the expession on e.g.
             *                              IQueryable<MyPocoTemplate>.Where(x => x.MyIdListField)
             *                              so keySelector.Body will contain the "x.MyIdListField" which is what we want to run
             *                              each constant expression against
             *      constant            ->  this is the constant expression (value) to be passed to the method
             */
            var typeArgs = typeOfTKey.IsArray ? new[] { typeOfTKey.GetElementType() } : typeOfTKey.GenericTypeArguments;

            expressions = constants.Select(constant => Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), methodName, typeArgs, keySelector.Body, constant));
        }

        /* 
         * Combine all the expressions into one expression so you would end with something like;
         * 
         * x => x.MyIdListField.Contains(AnId) OR x.MyIdListField.Contains(AnId) OR x.MyIdListField.Contains(AnId)
         */
        var aggregateExpressions = expressions.Select(expression => (Expression)expression).Aggregate((x, y) => orOperator ? Expression.OrElse(x, y) : Expression.AndAlso(x, y));

        // Create the Lambda expression which can be passed to the .Where
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(aggregateExpressions, parameter);

        return queryable.Where(lambda);
    }
}
```

This will then allow you to do a `.ContainsAnd` or a `.ContainsOr` with your lists. `ContainsAnd` means that *all* entries in the list *must* be present in the returned item. `ContainsOr` returns items where it contains *any* of the ID's in the list.

So your query would become:

```cs
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName).CreateSearchContext())
{
    //Filters related articles
    var relatedSearchQuery = context.GetQueryable<MySearchResultItem>()
        .Where(item => item.ItemId != currentArticle.Id.ToID())
        .ContainsAnd(item => item.Tags, currentArticle.Tags)
```

Where `currentArticle.Tags` is an already populated list of ID's.

SearchExtensions code taken from [Fortis Search Extensions](https://github.com/Fortis-Collection/fortis/blob/master/src/Fortis/Search/SearchExtensions.cs)